# On Group action and blocks of subgroups of the symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

this exercise is from Dummit and foote , page 117 , # 7.d

prove : a transitive  group $G$ is primitive on $A$ iff for each $a \in A$ , the only subgroups of $G$ containing $G_a$ are $G_a$ and $G$ 
where , $G_a$ is the stabilizer of $a$
$G$ is subgroup of $S_n$ - symmetric group -

my attempt ,

i proved one side , 
i proved that if  the only subgroups of $G$ containing $G_a$ are $G_a$ and $G$ 
then , the transitive Group $G$ is primitive

but i couldn't prove the other side the other side .

what i had thought in that if i can prove that , if $H$ is subgroup of $G$ that contains Ga then H = GB for some subset $B$ of $A$ , $a$ is in $B$ where 
$GB$ = { $g \in G$ : $g$ . $B = B$, . is group action operation }

then , I can prove the statement

but I don't know excatly how to do this ! I don't know if this is true to prove it !!

i hope that you give me some hints which able me to create my own solution

thanx !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is primitive on $A$. Hence the only blocks of $A$ are the singleton sets and $A$ itself. Take $a\in A$ and suppose $H\leq G$ is a subgroup such that $G_a\leq H\leq G$. Consider $Ha=\{ha:h\in H\}$.

- Prove that $Ha$ is a block.

Let $\sigma\in G$ as in the text. Suppose there exists some $x\in Ha\cap\sigma(Ha)$. So there are $h_1,h_2\in H$ such that $h_1a=\sigma h_2a$. This implies $h_1^{-1}\sigma h_2a=a$, hence $h_1^{-1}\sigma h_2\in G_a$. But $G_a\leq H$, and thus $\sigma\in H$ by left and right multiplying by $h_1$ and $h_2^{-1}$. But then $\sigma(Ha)=Ha$ since $Ha$ is invariant under the action of $H$, so $Ha$ is a block.

After proving that, we know there are two cases by primitivity, so either $Ha=A$, or $Ha=\{a\}$.

If $Ha=A$, for every $g\in G$ we can find $h\in H$ such that $ga=ha$, since the action is transitive. But then $h^{-1}ga=a$, thus $h^{-1}g\in G_a\leq H$, whence $g\in H$. It follows immediately that $H=G$ in fact.

The other case is simpler.

If $Ha=\{a\}$, then for every $h\in H$, $ha=a$, thus $H\leq G_a$, so $H=G_a$.

So if $a\in A$, and $H\leq G$ with $G_a\leq H\leq G$, we have either $H=G_a$ or $H=G$. So $G_a$ is maximal in $G$, as we needed to show.

Comment: why did you delete the first paragraph of your answer ?!!

Comment: @MathsLover It was needed to prove the converse direction, but I saw that you had already proven that. I removed it since it didn't seem relevant.

Comment: if i want to prove the paragraph which you had deleted .

 if A=B then

 GB = { g in G : g.B=B } = { g in G : g.A=A } = GA = G 

the other side as follows , 

if GB = G 

then G = { g in G : g . A = A } = { g in GB : g . A = A }

 this implies that A ⊆ B , but B ⊆ A then A=B 

is this proof is true for the paragraph deleted ?

Comment: the comment above is for you .

Comment: why x∈(x y)(B) ?? , x∈B , (x y)(x) = y ! so x is not in (x y)(B) .

Comment: and in this proof , we didn't use the fact that G= GB . so it's true also if G=\= GB , isn't it ?

Comment: i proved that Ha is block and stab(Ha)=H , so . the proof is complete but i need to understand the points i mentioned in last two comments

Comment: @MathsLover You're right, I removed that paragraph as I didn't think a full proof through since you were interested in the converse direction. Please ignore the deleted paragraph. If I were to prove the converse, I would do the following: Suppose $G_a$ is maximal for some $a\in A$. If $A$ has a proper nontrivial block $B$, then $G_B=G_a$, by part (a) of the exercise in Dummit/Foote. It is not the whole group as the action is transitive, and there are elements not in $B$. Since $G$ acts transitively, take $a,b\in B$ distinct, and let $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot a=b$. But $g\notin G_B$...

Comment: as all such actions fix $a$. But $b\in g(B)\cap B$, thus $g(B)=B$, since $B$ is a block. This is a contradiction, so $G$ must be primitive. I hope that clears things up. Either way, I don't think it is needed to prove the implication in question.

Comment: I understood your proof in the last two comments . but , this is not the matter ! now you proved one way , my question which i asked was about the other way , that means we need to prove that if G is primitive then Ga is Maximal .in  your answer , you gave some hints which to prove that Ha is block and then prove that stab(Ha) = H , i proved this . but to prove that Ga is maximal you need to prove lemma which says ,

Comment: if G is permutation group acts transitivly on A , B is subset of A , B is block under this action , then , A=B if and only if Stab(B)=G , you also gave me prove for this lemma but i had two feedbacks ! first is , why x∈(x y)(B) ?? and other is that we didn't use the fact that Ga=G .. we need to prove this to prove my question , i hope that i made it obivous for you about what i'm thinking in !

Comment: @MathsLover I've expanded the answer to make the intent of the proof clearer.

Comment: my friend ! the paragraph deleted from you answer is necessary to prove my question ! 

it's necessary to prove this statement : 
if G is permutation group acts transitivly on A , B is subset of A , B is block under this action , then , A=B if and only if Stab(B)=G

if you can't prove it then ! all the proof - which you explained in your answer - will not work . so we ara forced to prove it !!! so i hope that you give me a proof for it plz

Comment: can you make it obivous plz ?!!

Comment: @MathsLover The above should be a complete proof. What part is not obvious?

Comment: oh ! , you edit your reply ! i haven't noticed that !! 

thank you :) yes , it's complete .

what about the lemma ? 
if G is permutation group acts transitivly on A , B is subset of A , B is block under this action , then , A=B if and only if Stab(B)=G

how can we prove this lemma ? the proof you gave before wasn't complete